# Specific Example for the Existence of Partial Derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $\sigma$ has bounded first and second derivatives and refer to the following picture.  Why do we know that $u$ even has a partial derivative with respect to $y$?  As far as I can understand, (2.37) is justified by fixing y and applying Picard Lindelof, so I'm confused (this is on p. 296 of Karatzas and Shreve, for reference)

[image]

Comment: I haven't thought very deeply about this, but if I'm not mistaken, this must be due to the differentiability of solutions with respect to initial data (see here, for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18976/smooth-dependence-of-odes-on-initial-conditions). Someone can surely write a more detailed answer.